# C# winrt/metro app, WebView custom font

Tags: c#, fonts, webview, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Does anyone know how to load custom fonts in a WebView?
What I have tried:

```
@font-face {
     font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     src: url(Gloria.woff);
 }
```

According [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/23/about-webview-and-embedded-fonts.aspx).

But the thing is, that this works ONLY when we call `WebView.Navigate(urlToHtmlDocWithCustomFonts);`
But in my case I'm calling `WebView.NavigateToString(htmlStringWithCustomFonts);` and in this case custom fonts don't works!

Here is the project with sources from that tuto in case if you want to reproduce: [link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/g2yd7pxa2x5us8n/UsingFonts.zip).

So my question is, is it possible to load a html string into a webview with custom fonts?

Answer (score 0):

Use WebView.[NavigateToLocalStreamUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetolocalstreamuri.aspx) instead of NavigateToString. This will let you provide an [IUriToStreamResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.iuritostreamresolver.aspx) to stream referenced files such as images and your font files into your page. With NavigateToString you'd need to encode them within the stream as NavigateToString doesn't have context to look up and find referenced files such as Gloria.woff.

MSDN's [XAML WebView control sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=238582) demonstrates writing and using a resolver to stream in the referenced file.